# Node.js Backend/Server: Cannot `require` in `new Function` instance

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am trying to use `require` in a function initialized with `new Function`. Is there a way to allow require statements in a string

```js
// test.js

let fnString = `
const os = require("os");
return os.platform();
`;

const fn = new Function(fnString);
console.log(fn());
```

Running file `test.js`:

```js
$ node test.js
undefined:4
const os = require("os");
           ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> ({path}/test.js:8:12), <anonymous>:4:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> ({path}/test.js:9:13)
```

Successfully got it working with `node` REPL:

```js
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.4.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

> f = new Function(`
const os = require("os");
return os.platform();
`);

> f()
'linux'

>
```

Comment: Can you declare require as globally using var and try it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `require` as an argument to the function and pass it to the function like this:

```
let fnString = `
const os = require("os");
return os.platform();
`;

const fn = new Function('require', fnString);
console.log(fn(require));
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: require is not a function`

Comment: Forgot to pass `require` on the function call. This does work!